# Calling htable.get(rowID) in reduce task returns NULL for random rows

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

In my hadoop mapper task, i create a [key,value] = [sortKey,rowID] by scanning a hbase table
In the reduce task, when i do Result=Htable.get(rowID), some returns null, randomly, for diffrent rowIds.  But on querying in hbase shell, am able to fetch the same rowId. For an input hbase table row count of 1000 (mapper is able to fetch all these records), around 100 records returns htable.get(rowID) as null (in reducer), but all these 100 records are actually available in the table.

any idea why would a 'get' on htable return null randomly? any caching or memory tweaking would solve this?

am using hadoop-1.0.3, hbase-0.92.1

Comment: Are you using `String` rowID? If so, it is possible that you have trailing spaces in the reduce job.

Comment: no i use Text to store this rowId, and i just take it as it is from scan ouput in mapper.  If it had been an issue with trailing spaces, then, same set of rowIds would have returned null.  but in my case, different records return null, for each run, i.e., a rowId which returned null in first test run, will eventually return a record Result in another run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using hashmap to store those Text rowids, and cos of that, it was referring to the same location inside a loop.  Since i was doing some updates/deletes within the loop, some row ids were not found.  Either changing the hashmap to string, or creating a new Text object and then adding this to the hashmap solved the issue.